Is the statocyst in Xenoturbella homologous to the statocyst in Cnidaria?
The statocyst is a balance sensory receptor present in both Xenoturbella and in Cnidaria. Since Xenoturbella might be close to the urbilaterian according to some hipothesyses, I was wondering if it is known whether their statocyst organ is homologous (i.e. inherted from a common-ancestor) to the one in Cnidaria?

The statocyst is a balance sensory receptor present in some aquatic invertebrates, including bivalves,[1] cnidarians,[2] ctenophorans,[3] echinoderms,[4] cephalopods,[5][6] crustaceans,[7] and gastropods,[8] A similar structure is also found in Xenoturbella.[9]

So, are the statocyst in Cnidaria and in Xenoturbella homologous (i.e. coded by same or homologous hox genes etc)?

is there a reason why an organ always needs a hox gene coding for it? I know that this is a common mechanism of homology across animals but I'm not sure that it is a general rule, or that any gene can be said to "code for" a structure (as opposed to regulating its morphogenesis).

Hox genes control embryonic development by specifying how different body parts are connected and where. For example, a mutated hox gene in a fruit fly could result in an extra pair of wings, or a missing pair of legs.
